# Read a xlsx file without saving, which is coming from external api called from my server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, parsing, https, xlsx

```
const https = require('https');
var postData = JSON.stringify({
    'msg' : 'Hello World!'
});
let url;
url = "someurl2228.com";//dummy/random url (have removed actual url)
var options = {
  hostname: url,
  path: '/file/download/b8d61eff5314ac1ac982e5dbb9630f83',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {myheader:"somedata"}
};
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
  res.on('end',()=>{
    console.log('********************END********');
  });});
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);});
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

*I have removed actual urls. that is some just random url in my code above.*

From my code I am using https module to call a external rest api which in response sends me a xlsx file.
I want to read the file (without saving will be great).

Now, when I use Postman's *Send* button to call that external api I receive a unicode chracters in respose tab.
[image]
But when I use Postman's *Send and Download* button to call that external api I can get the xlsx file to save.
[image]

Now, I am able to replicate same unicode as in I am receiving with Postman's Send button in my NodeJS code using https module but don't know what to do next.
[image]

I want to read the xlsx file's data for further task.

Want to read the xlsx file's data without saving it to do further task.

Also Adding a snippet of my excel
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect the result as a buffer and then pass the result to the [XLSX's `.read`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-workbooks) method (which will then read it in memory).

Try this:

```
var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);
  
  // store buffer here
  let chunks = [];

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    chunks.push(d);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('********************END********');

    // feed buffer to `.read` method
    const workbook = require('xlsx').read(chunks, {type: 'buffer'});

    console.log('No more data in response.\nDo something with the workbook:\n\n', workbook);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have already tried thinking it was chunk but didn't worked.

Comment: res.on('data', (d) => {
    chunks.push(d);
});
res.on('end', () => {
            const workbook = xlsx.read(chunks, {
                type: 'buffer'
            });
            const sheets = workbook.SheetNames;
            const temp = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]])
        }

Comment: I have also updated my question with a snippet of my excel file.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in parsing logic. It is working correctly. Thanks.